# How to delete a field or row in Spatialite GUI

Tags: sql, qgis, spatialite

I am trying to find an easy way to remove columns/fields from an existing QGIS Spatialite database file. I am new to both Spatialite GUI and SQL, but I want to get the said job done. I right-clicked on a layer (for-China) and chose 'Show columns' from the context menu. Then I got an error message:

```
SQL error: "near "-": syntax error"
```

[image: SQL syntax error]

so I tried executing the statement:

```
PRAGMA table_info('for-China');
alter table 'for-China'
delete row 'note';
```

and the table showed up, but the NOTE row wasn't deleted:

[image: NOTE still appears (not deleted)]

I tried using COLUMN instead of ROW and also tried using DROP instead of DELETE but NOTE is still left untouched. I am confused on what to do to delete the NOTE row.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that spatialite uses the same escape characters as SQLite.  Hence, try double quotes:

```
PRAGMA table_info("for-China");

alter table "for-China" drop column note;
```

You should only need this for identifiers that are keywords or use characters other than alpha numeric, underscore (and perhaps a few others).

SQLite also recognizes backticks and square braces, as explained in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I also tried but it doesn;t work either:

    PRAGMA table_info("for-China");

    DELETE FROM "for-China"
    WHERE name = "NOTE";

Comment: @JAT86 . . . I don't know what "delete row" is.  You seem to want `drop column`.

Comment: I am confused with the Spatialite interface. I do not know if the column is **name** or **10**. (as shown in the image posted), but yes I want to drop that entire column containing NOTE under **name**.